# How do I integrate trace IDs into Django model errors for effective tracking in a Google Cloud-hosted environment?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

"I host a Django app on Google Cloud with PostgreSQL. Need help adding trace IDs to Django model errors for better tracking. Also, existing logs already have trace IDs."

"How can I add trace IDs to Django model errors in a Google Cloud-hosted environment?"